# UITableViewCell Segue SOMETIMES connects to wrong controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a very weird issue with my tableView, sometimes you click a cell and segues as it should, but other times it will segue to a random detailViewController.
I have 3 segues connecting from a UIViewController that contains tableview:

The segues "present modally" a detailViewController and pass a custom object "place" to the detailViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("PLACE SELECTED: SECTION \(indexPath.section) ROW \(indexPath.row) :: \(my_sections[indexPath.section])")
    self.selectedPlace = my_sections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
    let buttons_count = self.selectedPlace!.buttons.count
    switch buttons_count {
    case 0:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.NoButton.rawValue, sender: self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
    case 1:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.OneButton.rawValue, sender: self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
    case 2:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.TwoButton.rawValue, sender: self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
    default:
        break
    }

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (sender as? PlaceTableViewCell) != nil {
        if let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let place = self.my_sections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]
            navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            switch(segue.identifier!) {

            case SegueIdentifier.NoButton.rawValue:
                assert(segue.destination.isKind(of: PlaceDetailsViewController.self))
                let vc = segue.destination as! PlaceDetailsViewController
                vc.place = place

            case SegueIdentifier.OneButton.rawValue:
                assert(segue.destination.isKind(of: OneButtonViewController.self))
                let vc = segue.destination as! OneButtonViewController
                vc.place = place

            case SegueIdentifier.TwoButton.rawValue:
                assert(segue.destination.isKind(of: TwoButtonViewController.self))
                let vc = segue.destination as! TwoButtonViewController
                vc.place = place

            default: break
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The place object has place.buttons: [Button]

The three detailViewControllers are almost identical except they have different number of buttons.

The tableView decides which segue to use based on the size of place.buttons

Sometimes the tableView works like normal and other times it passes random cells. Unsure why.

Comment: In `prepare(for:)` why do you use the selected cell to get the place again? It is already in `self.selectedPlace`, or you could simply supply the place as the `sender` argument to `performSegue`.

Comment: Ok after following much of the advise given here, I think it IS a sorting error.  Somehow my_sections.rows does not match the order listed in the table!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your `prepare(for:` method to solve this as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    switch(segue.identifier!) {

    case SegueIdentifier.NoButton.rawValue:
        assert(segue.destination.isKind(of: PlaceDetailsViewController.self))
        let vc = segue.destination as! PlaceDetailsViewController
        vc.place = self.selectedPlace

    case SegueIdentifier.OneButton.rawValue:
        assert(segue.destination.isKind(of: OneButtonViewController.self))
        let vc = segue.destination as! OneButtonViewController
        vc.place = self.selectedPlace

    case SegueIdentifier.TwoButton.rawValue:
        assert(segue.destination.isKind(of: TwoButtonViewController.self))
        let vc = segue.destination as! TwoButtonViewController
        vc.place = self.selectedPlace

    default: break
    } 
}
```

Comment: so true. thanks for spotting this out. I am unsure if this will necessarily solve my problem because like the question says, it happens so randomly. All I can tell is that it is more likely to happen LATER in the day than earlier, and that my data relies on Google Places & Calendar API

Comment: Just implemented your changes and the problem is still ongoing. Very unsure why! Is it bad to attach segues between view controllers (as opposed from tableviewcell to view controller?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `my_sections` is array. Try sort it before access to it's items. I have simmular problem, when programm gets data from persistent store and items in the data array were unordered.

Comment: Is it possible that this problem has anything to do with the fact that some of my data is reliant upon Google Places & Calendar API? I only ask because I noticed that I once went past my Google Places API query limit and as soon as that happened, the tableview fixed itself. If you don't think so, disregard this question- I don't want to make it more confusing.

Comment: Also, I do sort the array when my_sections "didSet". I call this function:      
 `return self.my_sections.sort(by: { $0.index < $1.index})`

Comment: Do you sort subarray with rows? Maybe `self.my_sections.sort(by: { $0.index < $1.index})` sorts only groups, not rows in groups

Comment: `Is it possible that this problem has anything to do with the fact that some of my data is reliant upon Google Places & Calendar API?` . - Does Google API returns sorted lists of items and you code parse responses with same order each times?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and I am sorry to the people who took the time here, I did not give enough information for anyone to solve this problem.

my tableview gets information from

```
var my_sections: [Section] = [] {
        didSet {
            return self.my_sections.sort(by: { $0.index < $1.index})
        }
}
```

My "Section" model looks like this:

```
struct Section: Ordered {
    var section: PTPlace.Section
    var rows: [PTPlace]
    var sorted_rows: [PTPlace] {
        return self.rows.sorted(by: { $0.open_status.rawValue > $1.open_status.rawValue })
    }
}
```

I noticed something was up when rows were getting mixed up WITHIN sections but not between sections.

So I added the following line to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
    print("PLACE SELECTED: SECTION \(indexPath.section) ROW 
\(indexPath.row) :: \(my_sections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row].name)")
```

And I saw that the tableView was arranged very differently than how the rows were sorted, as if there were two different arrays. And sure as heck, that was the problem.

My tableView was displaying the sorted_rows array in the View while segueing to

my_sections[indexPath.section].**rows**[indexPath.row] 
instead of my_section[indexPath.section].**sorted_rows**[indexPath.row]

Problem solved. Silly mistake. Thanks again to everyone who helped me simplify my code.